# Set model variables in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1, akismet

In my model I have:

```
class ArticleComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rakismet::Model

  validates :text, :presence => true

  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user

  comment, permalink, request, username, email, text, remote_ip, 
      user_agent, referrer = nil

  def init_sp(comment_, permalink_, request_, username_, email_, text_)
    comment, permalink, request, username, email, text =
        comment_, permalink_, request_, username, email_, text_
    remote_ip = request_.remote_ip
    user_agent = request_.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 
    referrer = request_.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
  end

  rakismet_attrs author: username, author_url: permalink, author_email: email, 
      content:  text, permalink: permalink, user_ip: remote_ip, 
      user_agent: user_agent, referrer: referrer
  binding.pry
end
```

and in controller:

```
def create
  @article_comment = ArticleComment.new(article_comment_params)
  @spam = @article_comment.init_sp(@article_comment, params[:permalink], 
      request, username, email, article_comment_params[:text])

  if !@article_comment.spam?
  ....
```

So I need to set up field's like `ip`, `user_agent`, `text` in controller, how could I do this?

Now I see that my value's are nil (   why?

How to set rakismet_attrs value's with help of controller?

Comment: The raksimet docs suggests that it will grab ip etc from the current request automatically.

Comment: @FrederickCheung    i must set it in controller, becouse it want's to fetc it from db (like comment text etc)

Answer (score 1):

Some small pointers:

- in a model, if you want to save something to a column, use `self.column_name`
- you do not have to pass all the fields, since you are working on an instance which is already initialised with all the columns set correctly

So your model should look as follows:

```
class ArticleComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rakismet::Model

  validates :text, :presence => true

  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user


  def init_sp(permalink, request)
    self.permalink = permalink
    self.remote_ip = request_.remote_ip
    self.user_agent = request_.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 
    self.referrer = request_.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
  end

  rakismet_attrs author: user.name, author_url: user.permalink, author_email: user.email, 
      content:  text, permalink: permalink, user_ip: remote_ip, 
      user_agent: user_agent, referrer: referrer
end
```

And in your controller, just write

```
def create
  @article_comment = ArticleComment.new(article_comment_params)
  @article_comment.init_sp(params[:permalink], request)

  if !@article_comment.spam?
    ...
```

Also note, that according to the documentation you do not need to store request environment parameters, if you call `.spam?` inside a controller method (as you already do) it can access the `request` environment by itself.

Comment: ... to a column, use self.column_name... i didn't have it in model!

Comment: i didn't have email etc in comment model

Comment: not all of them, becouse i didn't have all them, also i could have user guest, which is not stored in model

Comment: Some columns will come from your `user`, so I adapted the answer a little.

Comment: @nathanvda, sorry for take your take. But could you look at my failed code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217458/rails-4-rakismet-akismet-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

> **Now I see that my value's are nil ( why?**

When you call `article_comment_params` the values are nil because Rails 4 uses [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) by default, so the parameters are filtered out because you do not explicitly `permit` them.

In the method `article_comment_params` you need to explicitly permit every parameter you want to *whitelist* / allow through the controller.

Change your `article_comment_params` method to include the `permit` method:

```
def article_comment_params
  params.require(:article_comment).permit(:comment, :permalink, :request, :username, :email, :text)
end
```

I don't know exactly what params you want to allow, so make sure you go through the list and include every parameter you need.

> **How to set rakismet_attrs value's with help of controller?**

The difficulty with this issue should be resolved when you whitelist the parameters using the method described above.

Comment: This does not apply completely. `remote_ip`, `user_agent` and `referrer` are not set from the params, but from the request environment. So this is not a strong parameters problem.

Answer (score 0):

Small upgrade on @nathanvda answer, also assuming you already have permalink in article_comment_params:

in controller:

```
def create

  @article_comment = ArticleComment.new(article_comment_params)
  @article_comment.spam_check_data = spam_check_data_from_request

  if !@article_comment.spam?
  ...

private
  def spam_check_data_from_request
    { 
      remote_ip: request.remote_id,
      user_agent: request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
      referrer: request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    }
  end
```

in model

```
class ArticleComment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Rakismet::Model

    validates :text, :presence => true

    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :user

    def spam_check_data=(data)
      self.remote_ip = data[:remote_id]
      self.user_agent = data[:user_agent]
      self.referrer = data[:referrer]
    end

    rakismet_attrs author: username, author_url: permalink, author_email: email, 
      content:  text, permalink: permalink, user_ip: remote_ip, 
      user_agent: user_agent, referrer: referrer
end
```

this allows you to decouple spam check data from the request object.

Comment: email  etc - i didn't have such fields in model

Comment: are these fields on associated User model? If yes, you can delegate to them, ie:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Module/delegate


delegate :email, :username, to: :user