# Rails 4 + Rakismet + Akismet not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, akismet

Rails 4

My application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Helpdesk
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.rakismet.key = '3sf1b9e19da3'
    config.rakismet.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Rakismet::Model

    has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
    belongs_to :status
    belongs_to :stuff
    belongs_to :department

    validates :customer_name, :customer_email, :subject, :body, presence: true

    def init_sp(permalink, request)
        self.permalink = permalink
        self.remote_ip = request.remote_ip
        self.user_agent = request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 
        self.referrer = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    end

    rakismet_attrs author: :customer_name, author_url: :permalink, author_email: :customer_email, content: :body, 
    permalink: :permalink, user_ip: :remote_ip, user_agent: :user_agent, referrer: :referrer

end
```

My controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.init_sp(ticket_show_path(Ticket.generate_id), request)

    t = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    t.debug "================================"
    t.debug @ticket
    t.debug @ticket.spam?
    t.debug @ticket.akismet_response
    t.debug "================================"

    if @ticket.save
      flash[:notice] = "Ticket created successfully. Message sent."
      redirect_to ticket_show_path(@ticket.token)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

My Log:

```
#<Ticket id: 5, status_id: 1, customer_name: "Drobazko", customer_email: "drobazko@gmail.com", token: "QOI-017-QIT-078-ULR", body: "Viagra", subject: "Subj", created_at: "2014-06-14 06:45:58"
, updated_at: "2014-06-14 06:45:58", stuff_id: nil, department_id: nil, permalink: "/tickets/XQT-689-KZR-289-USQ", remote_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_agent: ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/tickets/new"], referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/tickets/new">
D, [2014-06-14T09:45:59.484731 #7688] DEBUG -- : nil
D, [2014-06-14T09:45:59.485731 #7688] DEBUG -- : false
```

**I.e. t.debug @ticket.spam? returns nil, t.debug @ticket.akismet_response returns false**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Oh man: I tried to help some guy fix his code, it was not ment as an example of how to use rakismet. You should check the [rakismet docs](https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet).

- Imho the whole `init_sp` thing is not needed. As mentioned in the other answer: if you call `.spam?` from the controller, it will have access to the `request`.
- I would not make author_url=permalink, it should be a an url entered the author (of the ticket), which could be an indication if the author is a spammer. You can just leave it blank.
- Why don't you use the `Rails.logger.debug` ?
- Did you notice you just shared your akismet key with the world?

But aside of that, it is little weird that `.spam?` return `nil`, which from the source seems impossible. However a `akismet_response` could well be `false`. So afaik akismet just doesn't think it is spam.

From the rakismet documentation:

> The only guaranteed way to trigger a positive spam response is to set the comment author to "viagra-test-123".

Comment: Thank for useful reply. Something wrong with my implementation. Putting "viagra-test-123" I still get span? = nil and akismet_response = false.

Comment: Which version of the gem do you have?